# R::How to take the p-value from chisq.test output

Tags: r

I am doing a chisq.test and trying to assign the output to a variable.

```
> Output <- chisq.test(test[,k], test[,l])

> Output

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  test[, k] and test[, l]
X-squared = 7128, df = 36, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I want to access the p-value alone from the output or assign p-value alone to the ouptut.

Is there a way like:

```
Output$p-value
```

using which i can access the p-value alone? I dont want the rest of the information like df, X-squared values in the output.

Comment: try `p.value` instead.

Comment: @J.R. - Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
output$p.value
```

Open the help `?chisq.test`, and refer to the Value section.  It tells you what outcome is given by the function.
You can also try

```
names(output)
```

to find the component names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My P-value is 2.2e-16. but the output$p.value is returning as zero. Is there any way to get the actual value by itself.

Comment: `2.2e-16` is awfully close to `0`.  What you're seeing is a difference in formatting.  If there is a particular way you want your p-value formatted, you'll need to supply the formatting with something like `format`.

Comment: `str(output)` can be useful as well